# JS burger menu не работает

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, frontend

## (https://jsbin.com/vicesutovi/edit?html,css,js,output) Здесь все работает но локально почему то не работает#

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
                <title>JS Bin</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                <div id="text" class="burger__menu-item nav">
            
                  <span id="trigger" class="trigger">
                    <i></i>
                    <i></i>
                    <i></i>
                  </span>
                  <ul id="menu" class="mobile-list menu">
                    <li class="mobile-item"><a class="mobile-link mobile-link--active">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="mobile-item"><a class="mobile-link" href="photo.html">Фотографии</a></li>
                    <li class="mobile-item"><a class="mobile-link" href="form.html">Конкурс</a></li>
                    <li class="mobile-item"><a class="mobile-link" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                  </ul>
            
                </div>
              </body>
            </html>
            //css//
            body{
              background:brown;
            }
            .burger__menu-item {
              width: 100%;
              text-align: center;
              margin: 0; }
            .mobile-link {
              display: inline-block;
              text-decoration: none;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              color: #fff;
              min-height: 68px;
              display: -webkit-box;
              display: -ms-flexbox;
              display: flex;
              -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
              -webkit-box-direction: normal;
              -ms-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
              -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
              -webkit-box-pack: center;
              -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
              -webkit-box-align: center;
              -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
              border-top: 1px solid #000;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
              -webkit-transition: .3s ease-out;
              -o-transition: .3s ease-out;
              transition: .3s ease-out; }
            
            .mobile-link a[href]:hover, :focus {
              color: #d22856; }
            
            .mobile-link a[href]:active {
              -webkit-transition: .3 ease-out;
              -o-transition: .3 ease-out;
              transition: .3 ease-out;
              color: #fff;
              opacity: .3; }
            
            @media (max-width:640px){
              .menu{display:none;}
              .trigger{
                display:inline-block;
                margin:3px;
                cursor:pointer;
              }
              .trigger i{
                display:block;
                width:30px;
                height:6px;
                margin:4px auto;
                background:#222;
              }
              .show{
                display:block;
              }
            
            }
            
            //js//
            document.getElementById("trigger").onclick = function() {open()};
            
            function open() {
                document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle("show");
            }
```

[image: Что это означает]

Comment: а как вы подключаете pink.js? похоже что document.ready ещё не произошёл, поэтому по id ничего не находит.

Comment: `window.onload=()=>{/* сюда котика */};`